# Removing repeated sub-lists from a list

Tags: python, numpy

I have a list as follows:

```
l = [['A', 'C', 'D'], ['B', 'E'], ['A', 'C', 'D'], ['A', 'C', 'D'], ['B', 'E'], ['F']]
```

The result should be:

```
[['A', 'C', 'D'], ['B', 'E'], ['F']]
```

The order of elements is also not important.

I tried as:

```
print list(set(l))
```

Does numpy has better way

Comment: The list contents are only single characters? Or it's actually more complicated than that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Lists are not a "hashable" type and cannot be members of a set.

Frozen sets can, so we first convert to those (also making the sublists order-insentive), and later convert back to lists.

```
print map(list, set(map(frozenset, l)))
```

or if you prefer comprehensions,

```
print [list(x) for x in {frozenset(x) for x in l}]
```

I doubt numpy offers any "better" (for some definition of better) way.

This way is IMO the clearest and most pythonic.

---

The reason lists cannot be part of sets is that they are mutable, so the hash now is different from the hash after they are changed; being in a hash-based set would make for confusing behavior.

Comment: @PaulDraper Great! What's difference between tuple and frozenset?

Comment: @jose, a frozenset is a collection of unique elements that cannot be modified -- i.e. an immutable set. A tuple is like a "frozenlist" (though it is not named that); it is a sequence of elements that cannot be modified -- i.e. an immutable list.

Answer (score 0):

```
#!/usr/bin/python

l1 = [['A', 'C', 'D'], ['B', 'E'], ['A', 'C', 'D'], ['A', 'C', 'D'], ['B', 'E'], ['F']]
l2=[]

for l in l1:
    if l not in l2:
        l2.append(l)

print l2
```

OUTPUT

```
[['A', 'C', 'D'], ['B', 'E'], ['F']]
```

Answer (score 0):

The easiest and straightforward approach where you don't need to convert a non hashable type to hashable and vice versa (which has a performance impact), is to use itertools.groupby

Off-course, the order won;t be maintained but in any case OP categorically specified that it is not a strict requirement

```
>>> l = [['A', 'C', 'D'], ['B', 'E'], ['A', 'C', 'D'], ['A', 'C', 'D'], ['B', 'E'], ['F']]
>>> from itertools import groupby
>>> [k for k, g in groupby(sorted(l))]
[['A', 'C', 'D'], ['B', 'E'], ['F']]
```

Comment: Does your code work if the elements inside the sub-list are not in the same order?

Comment: No it won't, and OP never specified if that is a requirement. Nevertheless, it would be trivial to extend it to support orderless element set.